# Why is there a fatal error although it has echo out "connect successfully"

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

The following code is part of the main page that connect database with the main page. mainpage.php

```
<?php
 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'\dbh.php';
session_start() 
?>
```

this part of the code is the connection between database with the website. dhb.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "root";
$dp="ia";
$port=8889;
$link=mysqli_init();
$conn = mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $user , $password , $dp, $port); 
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table player";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
?>
```

This image is how the website tells me:
[image: This image is how the website tells me]

Comment: you have to use $link variable to execute query, no $conn variable. mysqli_real_connect function returns true or false, it does not return a connection object

Comment: In your code, "Connected successfully" has nothing to do with the if() logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_real_connect()` returns a boolean. It does not return a valid mysqli object. You create the mysqli object with `mysqli_init()`.

You are overcomplicating the database connection. You only need three lines to connect properly.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection